# Android NDK books or other materials

Tags: android, android-ndk

I know that more favorably to use the **NDK** instead of SDK, if you want to write faster application, so I want to know is there a good **books** how to programming on NDK? I know C/C++ languages, but I have no idea where to start. And if there aren't books, give an idea how to start. Please tell me is there a good books?
With all due respect, George.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Native-Interface-Programming-Reference/dp/0201325772/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1306148377&sr=8-6).

Answer (score 2):

*Pro Android Games* has some NDK coverage, IIRC.

I have some NDK coverage in *Android Beyond Java*, and that material will be migrating to a new *Tuning Android Applications* book shortly. In that same book, I also plan on covering using Renderscript on Android 3.x to fill the same "speed up the algorithm" use of the NDK. However, it has been over a decade since I wrote much C/C++ code, so my coverage of NDK and Renderscript will not be terribly expansive.

I am not aware of any NDK-centric books, though I have lost track of all the Android books that are out there.

In the end, the NDK is a GCC-based toolchain for creating libraries that work with your Java-based Android apps via JNI. So learning JNI, via the book that Mr. Borland suggested, gets you most of the way there. What that won't cover is all the truly Android-specific stuff (e.g., OpenSL, `NativeActivity`) that the NDK gives you access to.

The world could use a good NDK-centric book, but that's not my proverbial cup of tea. Or cup of proverbial tea. Or teacup of proverbs. Whatever. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to start by learning something about java (though technically in 2.3 and up you can escape having to write any yourself), and about the android activity lifecycle, and you may want to read some generic references on jni, particularly what *not* to do.

You'll also want to try some of the ndk samples to get familiar with the build system.

Comment: I know java, I write apps for Android using Android SDK

Comment: Ah, sorry, I formed the mistaken impression you were new to the platform.  Generally the easiest way to pick up something new - or in this case a new tool to add to your sdk knowledge - is to try to solve a suitable problem with it.  Accent on the suitable, as they claim the NDK is not necessarily faster, so pick something where it would clearly have an advantage.